# How to determine if level shifting is necessary between a 1.8V device (ICM-20948) and a 3.3V device (Arduino Nano 33 BLE)?

Tags: arduino, voltage, digital-logic, datasheet, level-shifting

### Background

I'm having trouble determining the requirements for interfacing between the [ICM-20948](https://invensense.tdk.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/DS-000189-ICM-20948-v1.3.pdf) and the [Arduino Nano 33 BLE](https://store.arduino.cc/usa/nano-33-ble). The biggest issue for me is that there is a detailed datasheet on the [nRF52840](https://content.arduino.cc/assets/Nano_BLE_MCU-nRF52840_PS_v1.1.pdf) that the Nano uses, but not the not the nano itself.

The ICM-20948 can operate with a VDD of 3.3V like the Nano, but the VDDIO is about 1.8V for the ICM-20948.

### For transmitting data to the ICM

The ICM datasheet states that the maximum logical LOW voltage is 0.3*VDDIO (=0.54V) and the datasheet for the nRF52840 states that the max output voltage for LOW logic output is VSS+0.4 (=0.4V). **Is this too close considering component thresholds?** (I also can't find the max voltage tolerances for these IMU IO pins in the datasheet, so I don't know if they could handle the 3.3V logic from the Nano)

### For transmitting data from the ICM

ICM has a min HIGH level output voltage of 0.9*VDDIO (1.62V) and the datasheet for the nRF52840 states that the min input voltage for logical HIGH is 0.7V*VDD (2.31V). **So I would definitely need some sort of level shifting for transmitting from the ICM to the Nano, right**?

**For the level shifting, could I just use resistors or would I need (or would it be more practical) to use dedicated level shifters?**

Comment: It's pretty obvious that's not going to work without translation; before you look at the low thresholds, look at the high *damage limits*.   Why do you want to use that part and not something simpler like an MPU-9250?  Given the realtively crudity of approach in using an Arduino board rather than integrating the BLE MCU yourself, and by the time you add level translation, it's unlikely you're going to come out much ahead power wise.

Comment: @ChrisStratton The reason I am not implementing the BLE MCU myself is the package it comes in is way out of my soldering abilities. The reason I am not using a different BLE MCU is because the RAM and Flash memory requirements for my project are very high and because I am trying to integrate with Tensorflow, which has limited supported MCUs. With respect to using the MPU-9250, I chose the ICM-20948 because of the low power consumption before considering level shifting; I'll have to look into the MPU-9250 as an alternative and see the differences.